# Identify volume button press and release in android

Tags: java, android

In my android app I want to get two notification   separately ,  when someone press the volume  button and release it. Using below method I can identify  volume  button press event .

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {



        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            {   

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "volume down button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                return true;
            }
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "volume up Button Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Now I want to know how can I identify volume button release event. If anyone aware about this please  guide me.

Comment: does ```public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)``` work?

Comment: @ John Chen , yes it worked. Thank u  very much for your support.